# Преобразование индекса столбцов в имена

Tags: python, pandas

Есть вот такой датафрейм полученный путем преобразований pipilene.fit_transform

```
             0         1         2         3         4         5
0     0.977568  1.038997  0.942926  0.509815 -0.177329  0.448802
1     0.977568  1.038997  0.226735  0.510422 -0.322728 -0.010582
2     0.977568  1.038997 -0.144131  0.466106 -0.499933  0.408505
3    -1.022946  1.038997 -0.388860  0.435550 -0.477214 -0.461907
4     0.977568  1.038997 -0.394878  0.387997  0.036226  0.021655
```

Я так понимаю столбцы в виде индекса получились, не могу ничего сделать теперь с эти dataframe. Как обратится к индексу столбца чтобы его переименовать? В мануале Pandas что то не могу найти полезного...

Comment: можете уточнить вопрос? Что именно вы хотите сделать? Обращаться к столбцам по их индексу или как переименовать столбцы? Может вы хотите получить те же имена столбцов, которые были до вызова `.fit_transform()`?

Comment: Да, я хочу их переименовать, но не пойму как обратится именно к столбцам( а не строкам) по индексу.

Answer (score 0):

Обращение к индексу столбца, такое же как и к индексу строки. На моем примере:

```
pd.DaraFrame([2], axis=1)
```